# angular routing using ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a api called https://swapi.co/api/ , here we have data called people, planet, film,species,vehicle and starship. here i want load to display these 6 names using ngfor and clicking on these names it should redirect each of its links in the api objct array.

```
 {
    "people": "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1", 
    "planets": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1", 
    "films": "https://swapi.co/api/films/?page=1", 
    "species": "https://swapi.co/api/species/?page=1", 
    "vehicles": "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/?page=1", 
    "starships": "https://swapi.co/api/starships/?page=1" 
}
```

for ex: if i click on key:people it should redirect its value. how can i do it using ngfor

Comment: What did you try until now? Any code? Anything? Are you blindly hoping that someone will do work for you?

Comment: can you show us your code (ngFor ... ) so we can help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all *ngFor works on array not on object. You need to convert your object into array with the help of Object.keys. Then use *ngFor on it. I have added a stackblitz for it.

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqtlnp

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in JSON format. Use `keyvalue` pipe in *ngFor.